# why show() method does not work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slideshow

I am trying to create a very simple slideshow using jQuery code with only 3 pictures.

I use the `next()` method to show the next image. This is how it should work:
When you click on a link (`class="next"`), a method is called which hides the current image and shows the next image and adds 1 to a counter (`i`) unless a 3rd image. Then, it hides the current image and shows first image (`id="first"`).

It's OK when you click on the first or second image and works correctly, but when you click on the 3rd image, it just hides the current image but it doesn't show first picture.

```js
var a = new Array();
$("#slideShow").children().first().show();
$("#slideShow").children().first().next().hide();
$("#slideShow").children("div").last().hide();
var i = 0

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (i == 2) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $("#first").show();
    i = 0;
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
    i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=slideShow>
  <div id="first">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg">
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg">
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are some ways I tried:

1. Using `css({"display":"block"})` instead of `show()` in jQuery
2. Using Javascript syntax instead of jQuery: `document.getElementById("first").show();`
3. Traversing instead of using id: `$(this).parent().parent().show;`

However these didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you `show()` the parent `<div>` but you also `hide()` the `<img>` / `<a>` children and never `show()` them again.

Remove:

```
$(this).hide();
$(this).siblings().hide();
```

and add:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

then you should be ok. Without changing any of your other logic, this gives:

```js
var a = new Array();
//$("#slideShow").children().first().show();
//$("#slideShow").children().first().next().hide();
//$("#slideShow").children("div").last().hide();
$("#slideShow>div").hide().first().show();

var i = 0
$(".next").click(function() {
  if (i == 2) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $("#first").show();
    i = 0;
  } else {
    //$(this).hide();
    //$(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
    i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=slideShow>
  <div id="first">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" width=200>
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" width=200>
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg" width=200>
    <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, that's right . i hid img and link individually ,but i showed whole div. that was my mistake. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your logic isn't quite correct as you hide the content of the slide div, then try and call `show()` on the slide div, not its content.

A better approach is to use a class to track the active slide and move to the `next()` one on button click:

```js
let $slides = $('#slideShow > div');

$(".next").click(function() {
  let $current = $slides.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
  let $target = $current.next('div');
  if (!$target.length)
    $target = $slides.first();
    
  $target.addClass('active');
})
```

```css
#slideShow > div {
  display: none;
}

#slideShow div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideShow">
  <div class="active">
    Screen 1
    <img src="img\Screenshot (1).png">
  </div>
  <div>
    Screen 4
    <img src="img\Screenshot (4).png">
  </div>
  <div>
    Screen 15
    <img src="img\Screenshot (15).png">
  </div>
  <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, that's right . i hid img and link individually ,but i showed whole div. thanks for new approach

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SwiperJS](https://swiperjs.com/)

However, this might be a quick solution  to your problem

```js
$(".prev").click(function() {
    //go to previous slide
    var activeSlide = $("div.active"),
      previousSlide = activeSlide.prev()

    //check if there is previous slide
    if (previousSlide.length !== 0) {
      activeSlide.removeClass("active")
      previousSlide.addClass("active")
    } else {
      alert("there is no previous slide!")
    }

  })


  $(".next").click(function() {
    //go to next slide
     var activeSlide = $("div.active"),
      nextSlide = activeSlide.next()

    //check if there is next slide
    if (nextSlide.length !== 0) {
      activeSlide.removeClass("active")
      nextSlide.addClass("active")
    } else {
      alert("there is no next slide!")
    }

  })
```

```css
#slideShow > div{
  display:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:120pt;
  width:250pt;

}

#slideShow > div img{
  width:100%;
}


#slideShow > div.active{
  display:block;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=slideShow>
   <div class="active">
     <img src="img\Screenshot (1).png" alt="slide1">

   </div>

   <div>
     <img src="img\Screenshot (4).png" alt="slide 2">

   </div>

   <div>
     <img src="img\Screenshot (15).png" alt="slide 3">

   </div>

 </div>
 <a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="next">&#10095;</a>
```